# Tensor Entry Selection Logic Divergence in PyTorch & Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

### Description

I'm setting up a `torch.Tensor` for masking purpose. When attempting to select entries by indices, it turns out that behaviors between using `numpy.ndarray` and `torch.Tensor` to hold index data are different. I would like to have access to the design in both frameworks and related documents that explain the difference.

### Steps to replicate

#### Environment

Pytorch 1.3 in container from official release: `pytorch/pytorch:1.3-cuda10.1-cudnn7-devel`

#### Example

Say I need to set up `mask` as `torch.Tensor` object with shape `[3,3,3]` and set values at entries `(0,0,1)` & `(1,2,0)` to `1`. The code below explains the difference.

```
mask = torch.zeros([3,3,3])
indices = torch.tensor([[0, 1],
                        [0, 2],
                        [1, 0]])

mask[indices.numpy()] = 1 # Works
# mask[indices] = 1 # Incorrect result
```

I noticed that when using `mask[indices.numpy()]` a new `torch.Tensor` of shape `[2]`, while `mask[indices]` returns a new `torch.Tensor` of shape `[3, 2, 3, 3]`, which suggests difference in tensor slicing logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get different results because that's how indexing is implemented in Pytorch. If you pass an array as index, then it gets "unpacked". For example:

```
indices = torch.tensor([[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0]])

mask = torch.arange(1,28).reshape(3,3,3)

# tensor([[[ 1,  2,  3],
#          [ 4,  5,  6],
#          [ 7,  8,  9]],

#         [[10, 11, 12],
#          [13, 14, 15],
#          [16, 17, 18]],

#         [[19, 20, 21],
#          [22, 23, 24],
#          [25, 26, 27]]])
```

The `mask[indices.numpy()]` is equivalent to `mask[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0]]`, i.e. the elements of the i-th row of `indices.numpy()` are used to select elements of `mask` along i-th axis. So it returns `tensor([mask[0,0,1], mask[1,2,0]])`, i.e. `tensor([2, 16])`.

On the other hand, when passing a tensor as index (I don't know the exact reason for this differentiation between arrays and tensors for indexing), it is not "unpacked" like an array, and the elements of the i-th row of the `indices` tensor are used for selecting the elements of `mask` along the axis-0. That is, `mask[indices]` is equivalent to `mask[[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0]], :, :]`

```
>>> mask[ind]

tensor([[[[ 1,  2,  3],
          [ 4,  5,  6],
          [ 7,  8,  9]],

         [[10, 11, 12],
          [13, 14, 15],
          [16, 17, 18]]],


        [[[ 1,  2,  3],
          [ 4,  5,  6],
          [ 7,  8,  9]],

         [[19, 20, 21],
          [22, 23, 24],
          [25, 26, 27]]],


        [[[10, 11, 12],
          [13, 14, 15],
          [16, 17, 18]],

         [[ 1,  2,  3],
          [ 4,  5,  6],
          [ 7,  8,  9]]]])
```

which is basically `tensor(mask[[0,1], :, :], mask[[0,2],: ,:], mask[[1,0], :, :])` and has shape `indices.shape + mask[0,:,:].shape == (3,2,3,3)`. So whole "sheets" are selected and stacked into new dimensions. Note that this is not a new tensor, but a special view of `mask`. Therefore if you assign `mask[indices] = 1`, with this particular `indices`, then all the elements of `mask` will become 1.